# Expresión regular para eliminar puntos

Tags: regex

Necesito una expresión regular que elimine los puntos entre dígitos y me mantenga todos los dígitos en la misma coincidencia.

Por ejemplo, en la frase:

> Hemos comprado un coche por 35.258€

me quiero quedar con:

> 35258

He probado con:

```
(?:(?![\.])[0-9])+
```

y con:

```
(\d{1,}\.(?=[^.]*)\d{1,})
```

pero ninguna de las dos me ha funcionado.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: solamente los puntos o el signo de "€" también?

Comment: @JeffersonCuji solo quiero quedarme con los números, lo normal es que solo vengan puntos, por lo que con eso me bastaría

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar el lenguaje/herramienta utilizado y el resultado esperado, tal cual se pide en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info ? ¿Que pasa si el texto tiene más de una cifra? ¿cuál es el resultado esperado cuando hay palabras entre los números?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías remplazar todo lo que no sea un número por un caracter vacío.

```js
text='35.258€'

console.log(text.replace(/\D/g,''))
```

Comment: No hay un lenguaje especificado, solo se requiere de la expresión regular.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es eliminar todos los caracteres (puntuación, $, €, etc.) y mantener solamente los números, podrías utilizar simplemente `\d+` y unir los grupos de números en el lenguaje de programación que estés utilizando.

En Python sería algo como:

```
output = ''.join(re.match('\d+', '35.258€').groups())
```

En este caso, RegEx detecta dos grupos de números: `35` y `258`, y `.join` los concatena como una cadena.